# InteliJ: Typescript auto check {} object against an interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea, redux

Here is example offending code of React component that is incorrectly connected to Redux.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ViewStyle, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { StoreState } from "../../store/storeState/storeState";
import { LogFactory, Logger } from "../../vlabs-js/general/logging/log";

interface DevCompProps {
    counter: number
}

class UnconnectedDevComp extends React.Component<DevCompProps> {
    private logger: Logger;

    constructor(props: DevCompProps) {
        super(props);

        this.logger = LogFactory.fromComp('DevComp');
    }

    render() {
        this.logger.info(`render(): props='${this.props.counter}'`);

        return <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'black', padding: 5}}>
            <Text>Counter:</Text>
            <Text>{this.props.counter}</Text>
        </View>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState) => {
    return {
        number: state.devState.counter
    };
};


export const DevComp = connect(mapStateToProps)(UnconnectedDevComp)
```

For the code to work correctly mapStateToProps should be

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState) => {
    return {
        counter: state.devState.counter
    };
};
```

Instead of

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState) => {
    return {
        number: state.devState.counter
    };
};
```

Is there a way to Compile/InteliJ-Warn check that the object returned by mapStateToProps matched the interface

```
interface DevCompProps {
    counter: number
}
```

So such a mistake would be flagged by IDE and not have to found by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no" because all the solutions here suck.  You'd probably have better luck dealing with function components and `useSelector` hooks.

When you map with a wrong key, your composed `DevComp` will be a component which requires that a `counter` prop be passed in when you call it so typescript gets that part right.

You can get the error to be raised by setting some of the generics on the `connect` function, but this seems like a pain.  The variables that we would set are the first, which is the props returned from `mapStateToProps`, and the third, which is the props that you expect the component to be called with.

```
const DevComp = connect<DevCompProps, {}, {}>(mapStateToProps)(UnconnectedDevComp)
```

Likewise, you can get an error to be raised by setting the return type on `mapStateToProps` to `Partial<DevCompProps>`.

You would need to override some of the types in the `react-redux` package in order to get that inference automatically.  But that sucks too.

We want to make it such that the props returned from `mapStateToProps` cannot have any keys which are not present in the component props.

You can't do it by manipulating the `MapStateToProps` type.  That has three variables, but none represent the type of the component to be mapped.  What you need is for `TStateProps` to be restricted.

```
export type MapStateToProps<TStateProps, TOwnProps, State = DefaultRootState> =
    (state: State, ownProps: TOwnProps) => TStateProps;
```

Ultimately the issue is the two-step nature of the `connect` HOC.  The creation of the "connector" is separate from applying it to a component, so the connector cannot depend on that component.

It's perfectly fine to do this:

```
const myWrapper = connect(mapStateToProps);
```

and get the type

```
InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<{ number: number; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, {}>
```

`myWrapper` is a function which can wrap **any** component and will add a prop `number` to it.  It doesn't know anything about the type of component that it will be applied to and does not care whether that component actually wants a prop `number`.

You would need to define your own function that combines the two steps into one function with two arguments so that the arguments can infer types from each other.  I don't have a complete solution.  `connect` has 15 different overloads and this type signature only describes one.  Also the implementation is an error, but the function typing does what you want.

```
const myConnect = <InnerProps, MappedProps extends Partial<InnerProps> , State = DefaultRootState>(
  mapStateToProps: (state: State) => MappedProps, Component: ComponentType<InnerProps>
  ): ComponentType<Omit<InnerProps, keyof MappedProps>> => {
    return connect(mapStateToProps)(Component);
}

export const DevComp = myConnect(mapStateToProps, UnconnectedDevComp)
```